# Regex pattern that will match similar or same strings in subject

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I don't even know how to properly set Title for this question. So I've been trying to make something, but I failed. I assume it'd be best to show a few examples below of what I want to accomplish.

```
// Let's say I have a list of some tags/slugs.

$subjects = [
   'this-is-one',
   'might-be-two',
   'yessir',
   'indeednodash',
   'but-it-might'
];

$patterns = [
    'this-is-one', // should match $subjects[0]
    'mightbetwoorthree', // should match $subject[1]
    'yes-sir', // should match $subject[2]
    'indeednodash', // should match $subject[3]
    'but-it-might-be-long-as-well' // should match $subject[4]
];
```

So, as one might see... Some of the patterns, do not fully/exactly match the given subject... So that's my problem. I want to make a regex, that would match all those possible variations.

I tried something basic, within foreach loop, but ofc it won't work as it's not fully matched...

```
if (preg_match("/\b$pattern\b/", $subject)) { // ... }
```

Any suggestions, explanations and code samples, please... I am trying to wrap my mind around regex, but not going well.

I will tag JS as well, because not necesserily has to do anything with `php` or `preg_match`.

Comment: Should necessarly be a regex??? This may be simple using other things!

Comment: your variations of subject are not too different so I'd just remove any non alphabetic characters from subject before comparing and then do a simple substring match. For anything more complex, I don't see how to do this other than using Machine learning.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - Not necessarily, but my assumption is that it may be required for such a thing?

Comment: Just do as @MirkoVukušić said: use `replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');` to remove any non-alphabetic characters, then use `includes` or `indexOf` to check whether it is a substring or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getMatchesOf(pattern, subjects) {
  var result = [];
  pattern = pattern.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');
  subjects.forEach(function(subject) {
    var _subject = subject.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');
    if(pattern.includes(_subject))
      result.push(subject);
  });
  
  return result;
}


var subjects = [
   'this-is-one',
   'might-be-two',
   'yessir',
   'indeednodash',
   'but-it-might'
];

var patterns = [
    'this-is-one',
    'mightbe',
    'yes-sir',
    'indeednodash',
    'but-it-might-be-long-as-well'
];

console.log(patterns[0] + " matches: ", getMatchesOf(patterns[0], subjects));

console.log(patterns[4] + " matches: ", getMatchesOf(patterns[4], subjects));
```